# Error adding a git submodule with specific branch

Tags: git, git-submodules, googletest

I am trying to add googletest as a submodule to my repo

`git submodule add -b v1.13.0 https://github.com/google/googletest.git external/googletest`

The specific branch v1.13.0 I have mentioned to take a stable release branch of googletest.
This is not branch name of my repo.

But on doing this I am facing this error:

```
fatal: 'origin/v1.13.0' is not a commit and a branch 'v1.13.0' cannot be created from it
fatal: unable to checkout submodule 'external/googletest'
```

Can someone tell why this error is coming and what is the correct way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for `git submodule add -b` is expected to be a branch, not a tag. Git clones the repository, looks up branch `origin/v1.13.0` and failed. You can do what you want in two steps:

```bash
git submodule add https://github.com/google/googletest.git external/googletest
git submodule set-branch -b v1.13.0 external/googletest
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-set-branch-b--branchltbranchgt--ltpathgt).